# Scorm module launch window to be able to resize

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scorm

I get the metadata and manifest file from people then when I launch it the window the window is too small or to big. In my Scrom controller I make provision for it to be resized and the new values be saved.

```
[HttpGet]
[NoCache]
public JsonResult ToggleLaunchResize(int scormModuleId)
{
    var module = ZincService.ScormService.GetScormModule(scormModuleId);
    if (module != null)
    {
        try
        {
            module.LaunchResize = !module.LaunchResize;
            ZincService.ScormService.UpdateScormModuleSettings(module);
            ZincService.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { hasLaunchResize = module.LaunchResize ? "Yes" : "No" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, "Error toggling HasLaunchResize property for scorm module with Id " + scormModuleId);
            return Json(new { hasLaunchResize = "unkown" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    else
        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If I select yes, why can I not resize the window?
Im a noob so dont know how this all works yet. 
please help?

thanks